# Android ksoap2 object reference null exception

Tags: android, ksoap

Here is my class which is calling the SOAP.  I'm getting the following error and I don't understand why.

`ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive.toString()' on a null object reference`

```
public class WebServicesController {

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://mywebsite.com:9000/";
private static final String ASMXURL = "Services.asmx?";

private String TAG = "PGGURU";
static SoapPrimitive resultString;

public static void SoapActionExecuteStoredProcedure(String METHOD_NAME,List<String> ArgumentPipeValue) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //add arguments in to
    for (String arg : ArgumentPipeValue) {
        String[] splitArgs = arg.split("|");
        request.addProperty(splitArgs[0], splitArgs[1]);
    }
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject (request);
    envelope.dotNet  = true;
    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(NAMESPACE+ASMXURL);


    ht.call (METHOD_NAME, envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    String result = response.getProperty(0).toString();

}
}
```

And here is how I call it.

```
  bt.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            List<String> myargs = new ArrayList<String>();
            myargs.add("_caseId|apples");
            try {
                WebServicesController.SoapActionExecuteStoredProcedure("DJProvider_Delete", myargs);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
```

Any pointers would be fantastic.  It could be I don't completely understand how to use KSoap, but i've followed a few tutorials and I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting error on this line

`**String result = response.getProperty(0).toString();**`

If that's the case please check whether you are getting any response at all. If you are getting no response at all, then that could be the reason.

**check if you are providing the arguments to the webservice correctly.**
When using SOAP you have to provide arguments in a particular structure, like a SOAP object inside another SOAP object. Check the SOAP object you are creating and the one required are the same.
(Just print the request.toString() for checking)

PS: I meant to put this in the comment section. But i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue recently, the problem was about internet permission, and i fixed it by adding this line of code into manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```